# Distribution upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 on Power PC

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, upgrade, powerpc

I am running a 1.67Ghz Powerbook with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with standard Unity desktop. The update manager suggests I update to 14.04.5 LTS. I know that Ubuntu is not available as a ppc image in 14.04. What would happen if I chose the distribution upgrade?

Comment: I think PowerPC is still supported by 14.04: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCDownloads. Therefore, your PC would upgrade.

Comment: Yes but the Unity interface is no longer supported so I am not sure what would happen. It could default to Gnome or just destroy the installation. I have until April next year to find out what to do...

Comment: Well, time for a leap of faith :) Make sure to keep plenty of backups though.

Answer (score 0):

This is not much of an answer, but at least I can tell you that in my case trying to do an upgrade has not caused anything bad to happen.  I have tried twice to upgrade my old G4 Mac Mini and each time I was unable to complete the upgrade.  But now I can't remember exactly what happened.  I do know that nothing broke and I just ended up with the same old 12.04LTS system.  Every now and then something tells me that there is an upgrade available, so I thought I'd check to see if anyone has yet been able to do such an upgrade on a PPC.